# Enumerating tabular data

Tags: tables, enumerate, counters

How do you enumerate tabular data like this?

```
a) stuff     stuff     stuff
b) stuff     stuff     stuff
c) stuff     stuff     stuff
```

I considered making a table then using a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
  \newcounter{ProblemPart}\stepcounter{ProblemPart}
  \newcommand{\partctr}{\mathrm{(\alph{ProblemPart})}\stepcounter{ProblemPart}}
  \(
    \begin{array}{rlll}
      \partctr & a & b & c \\ 
      \partctr & d & e & f 
    \end{array}
  \)
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: It is better to provide a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) both in order to demonstrate what you are trying to do and to help others help you. The MWE should like like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it should compile and contain close to the minimal amount of code needed to explain/demonstrate what you are asking. This saves a lot of time for everyone. Do you just want to count the items or label them as well?

Comment: @Andrew, see the second code block. The first code block demonstrates what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\renewcommand\therowno{\alph{rowno}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{!{\stepcounter{rowno}\strut\therowno)}lll}
   a & b & c \\
   d & e & f
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]